# Ubuntu 13.10 breaks NoMachine

Tags: session, ubuntu, gnome, fallback, nomachine

Twice since installing NoMachine a few years ago on Ubuntu, I've upgraded Ubuntu. And each time the upgrade broke NoMchine and I had to implement a workaround found on the web. So I wasn't surprised when I got around today to upgrading from Ubunto 12.10 to 13.10 that, once again, it broke NoMachine. But this time, I cań't find a solution after searching the web for a couple hours.

The problem is that for some reason Ubuntu is unable to execute the fallback to GNOME classic (no effects), which NoMachine says is required. I followed the instructions on the NoMachine site for configuring NoMachine 4, which is to `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback` and then insert `DefaultDesktopCommand "/etc/X11/Xsession gnome-session-fallback"` into the file `<installationDirectory>/NX/etc/node.cfg`.

Before and after doing this, when I try to create a gnome session from a remote NoMachine client, I get the error message

```
Xsession: unable to launch "gnome-session-fallback" X session ---"gnome-session-fallback"
not found: falling back to default session
```

And then it just displays a black screen.

I tried using gnome-session-flashback per some comments on other forums, and that didn't help. I also tried using xfce4 instead of gnome. That brings up a desktop, but then the client Seg Faults as soon as I try to interact with the desktop.

Comment: I selected xfce as my default desktop, and now I can connect to the xfce desktop from a NoMachine client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should make their mind up. NoMachine have updated their article, I think this is for the third time, to make sure Gnome users can use their software.

https://www.nomachine.com/AR07K00676

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't checked back with NoMachine since posting my question. I had already gotten xfce working with NoMachine; not sure that I changed anything after the initial failure I reported in the OP.